# OCaml internals: Exceptions

Tags: exception, compiler-construction, ocaml, internals, setjmp

I'm curious to know how exceptions are dealt with in OCaml runtime to make them so lightweight. Do they use setjmp/longjmp or do they return a special value in each function, and propagate it?

It seems to me that longjmp would put a little strain on the system, but only when an exception is raised, while checking for each function return value would need to check for every and each value after calling a function, which seems to me would put a lot of checks and jumps, and it seems it would perform worst.

By looking at how OCaml interfaces with C ( http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html#toc142 ), and looking at callback.h, it seems that an exception is tagged by using the memory alignment of objects ( #define Is_exception_result(v) (((v) & 3) == 2) ). This seems to indicate that its implementation doesn't use longjmp and checks each function result after each function call. Is that it? Or the C function already tries to catch any exception, and then converts it to this format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### OCaml exception handling

It doesn't use `setjmp/longjmp`. When a `try <expr> with <handle>` is evaluated, a "trap" is placed on the stack, that contains information about the handler. The address of the topmost trap is kept in a register¹, and when you raise, it jumps directly to this trap, unwinding several stack frames in one go (this is better than checking each return code). A trap also stores the address of the previous trap, which is restored in the register at raise time.

¹: or a global, on architectures with not enough registers

You can see for yourself in the code:

- [bytecode compilation](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/bytecomp/bytegen.ml?revision=11110&view=markup#l635): lines 635-641, two `Kpushtrap/Kpoptrap` bytecodes surround the `try..with`ed expression
- [native compilation](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/asmcomp/linearize.ml?revision=11110&view=markup#l254): lines 254-260, again instructions `Lpushtrap/Lpoptrap` around the expression
- [bytecode execution](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/byterun/interp.c?revision=11110&view=markup#l798) for the bytecode `PUSHTRAP` (places the trap/handler), `POPTRAP` (remove it, non-error case) and `RAISE` (jump to the trap)
- native code emission [on mips](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/asmcomp/mips/emit.mlp?revision=11110&view=markup#l449) and [on amd64](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/asmcomp/amd64/emit.mlp?revision=11110&view=markup#l613) (for example)

#### Comparison with `setjmp`

Ocaml uses a non-standard calling convention with few or no callee-saved registers, which makes this (and tail-recursion) efficient. I suppose (but I'm no expert) that's the reason why C `longjmp/setjmp` isn't as efficient on most architectures. See for example [this x86_64 setjmp implementation](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/um/sys-x86_64/setjmp.S) that looks exactly like the previous trapping mechanism plus callee-registers save.

This is taken into account in the [C/OCaml interface](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html): the usual way to call a Caml function from C code, `caml_callback`, doesn't catch OCaml-land exceptions; you have to use a specific `caml_callback_exn` if you wish to, which setups its trap handler *and* saves/restores callee-saved registers of the C calling convention. See eg. [the amd64 code](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/asmrun/amd64.S?view=markup#l378), which saves the registers then jump to [this label](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/release/3.12.1/asmrun/amd64.S?view=markup#l290) to setup the exception trap.

Comment: Wow! Very nice! Thank you! Do you know why setjmp/longjmp doesn't use a similar approach? Is there any way to access those primitives from C other than __asm__ calls? Thank you again!

Comment: @Waneck I suppose `setjmp/longjmp` use a similar implementation on architectures that make this practical. But the callee-saved registers of the calling convention make those things more costly. I added a remark about them.