# CLR vs OCaml exception overhead

Tags: exception, f#, clr, ocaml

Reading *Beginning F# - Robert Pickering* I focused on the following paragraph:

> Programmers coming from an OCaml background should be careful when
>   using exceptions in F#. Because of the architecture of the CLR,
>   throwing an exception is pretty expensive—quite a bit more expensive
>   than in OCaml. If you throw a lot of exceptions, profile your code
>   carefully to decide whether the performance costs are worth it. If the
>   costs are too high, revise the code appropriately.

Why, because of CLR, throwing an exception is more expensive if `F#` than in `OCaml`? And what is the best way to revise the code appropriately in this case?

Comment: There was a previous [discussion of the lightweightness of OCaml exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564025/ocaml-internals-exceptions)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield thanks, however I'm more interested in aspects concerning CLR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reed already explained why .NET exceptions behave differently than OCaml exceptions. In general, .NET exceptions are suitable only for *exceptional* situations and are designed for that purpose. OCaml has more lightweight model and so they are used to also implement some control flow patterns.

To give a concrete example, in OCaml you could use exception to implement breaking of a loop. For example, say you have a function `test` that tests whether a number is a number we want. The following iterates over numbers from 1 to 100 and returns first matching number:

```
// Simple exception used to return the result
exception Returned of int

try
  // Iterate over numbers and throw if we find matching number
  for n in 0 .. 100 do
    printfn "Testing: %d" n
    if test n then raise (Returned n)
  -1                 // Return -1 if not found
with Returned r -> r // Return the result here
```

To implement this without exceptions, you have two options. You could write a recursive function that has the same behaviour - if you call `find 0` (and it is compiled to essentially the same IL code as using `return n` inside `for` loop in C#):

```
let rec find n = 
  printfn "Testing: %d" n
  if n > 100 then -1  // Return -1 if not found
  elif test n then n  // Return the first found result 
  else find (n + 1)   // Continue iterating
```

The encoding using recursive functions can be a bit lengthly, but you can also use standard functions provided by the F# library. This is often the best way to rewrite code that would use OCaml exceptions for control flow. In this case, you can write:

```
// Find the first value matching the 'test' predicate
let res = seq { 0 .. 100 } |> Seq.tryFind test
// This returns an option type which is 'None' if the value 
// was not found and 'Some(x)' if the value was found.
// You can use pattern matching to return '-1' in the default case:
match res with
| None -> -1
| Some n -> n
```

If you're not familiar with option types, then take a look at some introductory material. [F# wikibook has a good tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Option_Types) and [MSDN documentation has useful examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) too.

Using an appropriate function from the `Seq` module often makes the code a lot shorter, so it is preferrable. It may be slightly less efficient than using recursion directly, but in most of the cases, you don't need to worry about that.

**EDIT:** I was curious about the actual performance. The version using `Seq.tryFind` is more efficient if the input is lazily generated sequence `seq { 1 .. 100 }` instead of a list `[ 1 .. 100 ]` (because of the costs of list allocation). With these changes, and `test` function that returns 25th element, the time needed to run the code 100000 times on my machine is:

```
exceptions   2.400sec  
recursion    0.013sec  
Seq.tryFind  0.240sec
```

This is extremely trivial sample, so I think the solution using `Seq` will not generally run 10 times slower than equivalent code written using recursion. The slowdown is probably due to the allocation of additional data structures (object representing the sequence, closures, ...) and also due to additional indirection (the code needs numerous virtual method calls, instead of just plain numeric operations and jumps). However, exceptions are even more costly and don't make the code shorter or more readable in any way...

Comment: +1 I must definitely  read your book. Just one thing, why using a function from Seq may be less efficient than using recursion directly?

Comment: @gliderkite I run a primitive test and added some performance info.

Answer (score 12):

Exceptions in the CLR are very rich, and provide a lot of detail.  Rico Mariani posted an (old, but still relevant) post on [the cost of exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/19/44697.aspx) in the CLR which details some of this.

As such, throwing an exception in the CLR has a higher relative cost than in some other environments, including OCaml.

> And what is the best way to revise the code appropriately in this case?

If you *expect* the exception to be raised in normal, non-exceptional circumstances, you can rethink your algorithm and API in a way that avoids the exception entirely.  Try to provide an alternative API where you can test for the circumstance prior to causing the exception to be raised, for example.

Comment: The `option` type is extremely relevant here.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, exactly.  Often, you can use `None` instead of using exceptions.

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont' know `None` and `option` type. Could you elaborate these relevant aspects?

Comment: The Option type is similar too but better than having null references. It is a type with two constructors Some a and None.  Basically None is Null and Some a is a populated value.  It is better than null because the type system enforces None handling when you pattern match to get your value out, thus you can never unknowingly get a null ref exception.

Comment: "Exceptions in the CLR are very rich". I think it would be nice if your answer elaborated on some of this richness. OCaml exceptions contain stack traces, auxiliary data (e.g. error messages), can be reraised and so on. So what exactly does .NET provide that explains why it is 600x slower than OCaml?

Comment: @JonHarrop - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx for a description of some of the intricacies of SEH and the .NET exception model.  I suspect that being built on SEH has some benefits (e.g. marshaling exceptions between native and managed code, ability for debuggers to break on first chance exceptions, support for `finally` blocks).  Whether these features are worth the performance cost is of course debatable.

Answer (score 8):

> Why, because of CLR, throwing an exception is more expensive if F# than in OCaml?

OCaml was heavily optimized for the use of exceptions as control flow. In contrast, exceptions in .NET have not been optimized at all.

Note that the performance difference is *huge*. Exceptions are around 600× faster in OCaml than they are in F#. Even C++ is around 6× slower than OCaml in this regard, according to my benchmarks.

Even though .NET exceptions allegedly provide more (OCaml provides stack traces, what more do you want?) I cannot think of any reason why they should be as slow as they are.

> And what is the best way to revise the code appropriately in this case?

In F#, you should write "total" functions. This means your function should return a value of a union type indicating the kind of result, e.g. normal or exceptional.

In particular, calls to `find` should be replaced with calls to `tryFind` that return a value of the `option` type that is either `Some` value or `None` if the key element was not present in the collection.

Comment: `I cannot think of any reason why they should be as slow as they are.` This is exactly what I'm asking. The link [_The Cost of Exceptions_](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/19/44697.aspx) posted by Reed Copsey explains very simply why this slowness.

Comment: @gliderkite That article states that .NET is slow and describes workarounds (avoid this part of .NET) but I don't think it describes why. I think the answer is simply that Microsoft never bothered optimizing it.

Comment: `I don't think it describes why` unfortunately it is so, but I don't think that Microsoft never bothered optimizing it, what gain thay would have obtained in this way?