# How to map a sequence of discriminated unions (where all items are of the same case) onto a sequence of items of the type of the case?

Tags: f#

I have the following:

```
type union1 =
    | Case1 of string
    | Case2 of int

let union1s = seq { for i in 1..5 do yield case2 i }
```

How do I change `union1s` to a sequence of type `seq<int>`?

Something like:

```
let matchCase item =
    match item with
    | Case1 x -> x
    | Case2 x -> x

let case2s = Seq.map matchCase union1s
```

This attempt does not work because matchCase can not return two different types.

The suggested answers have the same problem (if I understand correctly)

```
let matchCaseOpt = function
    | Case1 x -> Some x
    | Case2 x -> Some x
    | _ -> None

let case2s = Seq.choose matchCaseOpts unions1s
```

The expression Some x expects expects type Option string in the match for Case2

I have solved my particular use-case by using a DU of sequences.

```
type Union1s =
    | Case1s of seq<string>
    | Case2s of seq<int>
```

Comment: Please note that's not a suggested answer. Case1 is wrong, should be None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following reflection-based, general purpose implementation:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let filterUnionCases (branch : Expr<'T -> 'Union>) (inputs : 'Union list) =
    let rec getUnionCase (e : Expr) =
        match e with
        | NewUnionCase(unionCaseInfo,_) -> unionCaseInfo
        | Lambda(_, body) -> getUnionCase body
        | Let(_, TupleGet _, body) -> getUnionCase body
        | _ -> invalidArg "branch" "not a union case constructor"

    let getBranchContents (uci : UnionCaseInfo) (u : 'Union) =
        let uci', fields = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(u, typeof<'Union>)
        if uci = uci' then
            match fields with
            | [| field |] -> field :?> 'T
            | _ -> FSharpValue.MakeTuple(fields, typeof<'T>) :?> 'T
            |> Some
        else None

    let uci = getUnionCase branch
    inputs |> List.choose (getBranchContents uci)


filterUnionCases <@ Case1 @> [ Case1 "string1" ; Case2 2 ; Case1 "string2" ] //  [ "string1" ; "string2" ]
filterUnionCases <@ Case2 @> [ Case1 "string1" ; Case2 2 ; Case1 "string2" ] //  [ 2 ]
```

This should work even in union cases that contain multiple fields.

Comment: Thanks. I can follow what's going on, but it sure stretches what I'm using now. Lot's to learn

Comment: You should keep in mind that this is *slow*, since it uses reflection. If performance is important to you, you should go for the solutions offered by the other posters.

Comment: I will, I circumvented my problem by using a DU of sequences. Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

You are assuming your sequence contains not a single case1, so if this is not true you need to throw an exception.

```
let matchCase item =
    match item with
    | Case1 x -> failwith "Unexpected Case1"
    | Case2 x -> x

let case2s = Seq.map matchCase union1s
```

An alternative approach, if you are not sure the sequence contains always the same case is to use an Option

```
let matchCase item =
    match item with
    | Case1 x -> None
    | Case2 x -> Some x
```

Then it depends on how you will handle these cases, you can just filter out the `None` values using Seq.choose instead of Seq.map as shown on the other answer.

Which approach to follow depends if you consider having an argument with Case1s an exceptional case or part of the logic of your program. There was a question regarding this [F#: Some, None, or Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469815/f-some-none-or-exception) recently.

Using a DU of sequences is correct if you are not mixing Cases, that way your DU Type restrict your domain to the actual cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks. However sometimes the seq contains items of only case1

Comment: Then use the alternative version and check the results. You can decide then what to do with the NONEs. May be filter them out with Seq.choose as shown on the other answer. It really depends if it's an Exceptional case or not.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative:

```
let matchCaseOpt item =
    match item with
    | Case2 x -> Some(x)
    | _ -> None

let case2s = union1s |> Seq.choose matchCaseOpt
```

This version will drop any cases other than Case2, where Gustavo's solution will throw an exception if those occur. Which solution is best depends on your exact requirements, of course.

Note that this solution uses Seq.choose rather than Seq.map.